# Want to add CGST + SGST in Subtotal in JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this HTML Code from Invoice:-

```
<tr>
   <td colspan="3" class="blank"></td>
   <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Subtotal Rs.</td>
   <td td class="total-value">
      <textarea id="subtotal" name="i_subt" readonly="readonly"></textarea>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td colspan="3" class="blank"></td>
   <td colspan="2" class="total-line">CGST (2.5%) Rs.</td>
   <td td class="total-value">
       <textarea id="cgst" name="i_cgst">.00</textarea>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="3" class="blank"></td>
  <td colspan="2" class="total-line">SGST (2.5%) Rs.</td>
  <td td class="total-value">
     <textarea id="sgst" name="i_sgst">.00</textarea>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="3" class="blank"></td>
  <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Total Rs. </td>
  <td class="total-value">
       <textarea id="total" name="i_ttl" readonly="readonly"></textarea>
  </td>
</tr>
```

i have this code, I want too add 2 taxes namely CGST (2.5%) & SGST (2.5%) in subtotal...

```
    function update_total() {
  var total = 0;
  $('.price').each(function(i){
    price = $(this).html().replace("$","");
    if (!isNaN(price)) total += Number(price);
  });

  total = roundNumber(total,2);

  $('#subtotal').html(total);

  //NEED some Code here to add CGST & SGST to Total

  $('#total').html(total);
  
  update_balance();
}
```

[image]

My Code is adding `"Qty * Unit Price = Item total"` of each item in Subtotal Perfectly. I need some code to add `CGST * SGST` in `Sub-Total` to make Total.

Answer (score 1):

Use the equation `(total * 2.5)/100` to find GST @ 2.5%.

See below code to find the GST of Subtotal and add it to total

```
function update_total() {
  var total = 0;
  var gst = 0;
  $('.price').each(function(i){
    price = $(this).html().replace("$","");
    if (!isNaN(price)) total += Number(price);
  });

  total = roundNumber(total,2);

  $('#subtotal').html(total);

  //NEED some Code here to add CGST & SGST to Total
  gst = roundNumber((total * 2.5)/100,2);
  $('#cgst').html(gst);
  $('#sgst').html(gst);

  $('#total').html(total + gst);
  
  update_balance();
}
```

Comment: i did as u suggested but Nothing Happens. Please Suggest any other solution... @munawir